# How do I prove this proposition on Change of Coordinates of Surfaces?

Tags: differential-geometry

Given:

$ S \subset \mathbb{R}^3 $ is a surface  with $p \in S$. $X: U \to \mathbb{R}^3 $ is a parametrization of a neighborhood of $p$. $Y: U' \to \mathbb{R}^3 $ is a reparametrization of $X$ with $Y= X \circ F$, such that $F: U' \to U$ is a diffeomorphism. Let $q \in U$ and $q' \in U'$ such that $X(q)= p $ and $F(q')= q$.

If $\vec A \in T_pS$, where $T_pS$ is the set of all tangent vectors of $S$ at $p$, then we have that $\vec A$ must be a linear combination of the basis of $T_pS$, that is

(1) $\vec A= a_1 X_u(q)+ a_2 X_v(q)$, and

(2) $\vec A= b_1 Y_s(q')+ b_2 Y_t(q')$

Show that
 $$\begin{pmatrix} b_1 \\ b_2 \end{pmatrix} = [dF_{q'} ^{-1}] \begin{pmatrix} a_1 \\ a_2 \end{pmatrix} $$

I honestly have no idea how to start it. I would appreciate if you can show me how to start it, and I might be able to continue on from there. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

By the chain rule, $X_u=Y_ss_u+Y_tt_u$ and $X_v=Y_ss_v+Y_tt_v$. Thus
$$A=a_1X_u+a_2X_v=a_1(Y_ss_u+Y_tt_u)+a_2(Y_ss_v+Y_tt_v)=(s_ua_1+s_va_2)Y_s+(t_ua_1+t_va_2)Y_t,$$ 
that is $b_1=s_ua_1+s_va_2$ and $b_2=t_ua_1+t_va_2,$ 
i.e. 
$$
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
b_1\\
b_2
\end{array}\right)
=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
s_u & s_v\\
t_u & t_v
\end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
a_1\\
a_2
\end{array}\right),
$$
and notice the matrix is just $d(F^{-1})=(dF)^{-1}$.